# How many integers are between $p^2$ and ($p^2$ + q) that are evenly divisible by p and not divisible by a prime less than p?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$ be a prime number and $q$ be the product of all prime numbers less than or equal to $p$.

What is the general formula to calculate the number of integers between $p^2$ and $(p^2 + q)$ that are evenly divisible by $p$ and no other prime less than $p$ ?

For example, if $p = 7$ and $q = 7*5*3*2 = 210$. There are $9$ integers between $49$ and $259$ are evenly divisible by $7$ and not evenly divisible by $5$ or $3$ or $2$. They are $49$, $77$, $91$, $119$, $133$, $161$, $203$, $217$ and $259$.

Comment: Why do you think that such a formula exists?

Comment: Inclusive if $p^2$ and $p^2+q,$ or excluding the endpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number $m$ with $k\leq m< k+q$ are a unique set of representatives of $\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z.$ So the number divisible by $p$ and no smaller prime is the same as the number $0\leq m<q$ with that property.

Let $p_1<p_2<p_3<\cdot <p_n=p$ be the primes $\leq p.$

Then for any $(x_i)_{i=1}^n$ with $0\leq x_i<p_i$ there will be exactly one $0\leq x<q$ such that $x\equiv x_i\pmod {p_i},$ and each such $x$ determines one sequence $(x_i).$

The numbers you want are the numbers with $x_n=0$ and $x_i\neq 0$ for $i<n.$ That means the number of such numbers is exactly $$C=(p_1-1)(p_2-1)\cdots(p_{n-1}-1).$$ You can also write it as: $$C=\frac1{p-1}\phi(q)=\phi\left(\frac qp\right)$$

The condition - divisibly by $p$ but no smaller prime - describes exactly the elements of order $q/p$ in the cyclic group $(\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z,+)$ which is known to be $\phi(q/p).$

---

You can probably estimate $\log C$ by writing it as:

$$\log C=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\log p_i+\log \left(1-\frac1{p_i}\right)\right)$$

$\theta(y)=\sum_{p<y}\log p$ is the [Chebyshev function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function?wprov=sfti1), which has know estimates, and we can using $\log(1-x)=-x+O(x^2)$ for $|x|\leq \frac12$ to get estimates of $\log(1-1/p_i).$

Ultimately, we get:

$$\log C=p+O\left(\frac p{\log p}\right)$$

If the Riemann Hypothesis is true, you get:

$$\log C=p+O\left(p^{\frac12+\epsilon}\right)$$
For any $\epsilon>0.$

---

The precise value depends on whether you want to count to be inclusive of both, one, or none of $p^2$ and $p^2+q.$ Both endpoints satisfy your condition, so if you include both, you need to add $1$ to $C$ and if you include neither endpoint you must subtract $1$ from $C.$ If you allow only one endpoint, you get exactly $C.$

It doesn't affect the estimate much, of course.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.